# Pardot API send email with custom fields

Tags: email, api, pardot

I'm new to Salesforce and Pardot so sorry for maybe dumb question.

However i'm interested if there is a way of passing any additional data (metadata) to emails send using Pardot API so it can be obtained later - same way as email contents or stats?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Currently there isn't a way to add extra metadata (or Custom Fields) to Pardot around the sending of an Email. You would need to store this additional context in some other system (perhaps a Salesforce custom object?)